# How can I use str_detect() in combination with the & operator?

Tags: r, tidyverse, stringr

When using str_dectect() you can use the | operator like so...

```
example_df <- data.frame(
   letters = c("A B C", "C B E", "F C B", "A D E", "F G C")
)

example_df %>% filter(str_detect(letters, "B|C"))
```

And it will return all rows except the fourth (where letters = "A D E").

I want to do the same with str_detect() but looking for a combination of letters.

I imagined you could just replace the | operator with the & operator and the following would return all rows except the last two.

```
example_df <- data.frame(
   letters = c("A B C", "C B E", "F C B", "A D E", "F G C")
)

example_df %>% filter(str_detect(letters, "B&C"))
```

However, this doesn't work. Does anyone know how I can make this work using str_detect or another tidyverse method (I can get it to work with grepl but need to find a tidyverse solution).

Comment: Perhaps: `str_detect(letters, "C") & str_detect(letters, "B")` or `str_detect(letters, "(B.*C|C.*B)")`.

Comment: This definitely works. I guess I was hoping there would be something a little more succinct since, in reality, my list is longer than two patterns. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: How would you do it with `grepl`?

Comment: My colleague said they could already manage it and linked me to this... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40816147/how-to-find-rows-which-contain-words-in-a-given-list-of-words-not-only-a-certai

But we wanted to do it within filter simply

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using Perl-style "non-consuming lookahead":

```r
example_df <- data.frame(
  letters = c("A B C", "C B E", "F C B", "A D E", "F G C", "B B E")
)

library(tidyverse)

example_df %>% filter(str_detect(letters, "(?=.*B)(?=.*C)"))
#>   letters
#> 1   A B C
#> 2   C B E
#> 3   F C B
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

This looks for anything followed by B, but doesn't advance; then it looks for anything followed by C.  That's accepted by default in `str_detect`, but if you wanted to do the same sort of thing in base R functions, you'd need the `perl = TRUE` option, e.g.

```
grep("(?=.*B)(?=.*C)", example_df$letters, perl = TRUE, value = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `&` operator inside the `filter` and add another `str_detect`

```
example_df %>%
  filter(str_detect(letters, "B")&
           str_detect(letters, "C"))
```

Maybe you don't want to repeat the `str_detect` each time you need another match in the same column. Especially when you have many patterns. You can make a function to handle this situation

```
example_df  |>
  str_detect_and(letters, c('B','C'))
#   letters
# 1   A B C
# 2   C B E
# 3   F C B
```

Here's the definition of `str_detect_and`

```
str_detect_and <- function(df, col_name, terms){
  
  col_name <- enquo(col_name)
  
  df <- Reduce(
    function(dfRes, term)
    filter(dfRes, str_detect(!!col_name, term)),
    x = terms[-1],
    init = filter(df, str_detect(!!col_name, terms[1]))
    )
  
  return(df)
}
```

Essentially, `str_detect_and(example_df, letters, c('B','C'))` is the same as `filter(filter(example_df, str_detect(letters, 'B')), str_detect(letters, 'C'))`, and if you need it, you can pass the snippet into another `filter(str_detect)` with the same `letters` column. That's why we can use the `Reduce` function.